# Migrating from a database first to code first model with identity using ASP.NET Core and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I've been developing a website for quite some time. Recently I realized that I would need and identity model (using ASP.NET's build-in functionality), as I'd like to convert the database first model into a code first.

Now, I realize that this is a quite drastic change in structure, but nevertheless I assume that it should be possible.

**STRUCTURE**

I've pulled in the following packages to prepare my migration and convertion:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "7.1.4",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0"
```

This is what I've found mandatory for this to work (various articles, blogposts and what not).

From here, I set up my context `DatabaseContext`, like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        :base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        <!-- I'm not interested in using all IdentityUser properties, hence ignoring those not needed -->
        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users")
            .Ignore(x => x.ConcurrencyStamp)
            .Ignore(x => x.LockoutEnabled)
            .Ignore(x => x.LockoutEnd)
            .Ignore(x => x.NormalizedEmail)
            .Ignore(x => x.NormalizedUserName)
            .Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumber)
            .Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
            .Ignore(x => x.TwoFactorEnabled);

        <!-- Again, ignoring the properties I do not want from IdentityRole -->
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles")
            .Ignore(x => x.ConcurrencyStamp)
            .Ignore(x => x.NormalizedName);

        <!-- Adding the rest of the identity models, and mapping these into their correct database table -->
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("UserTokens");
    }

    public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
    <!-- etc... -->
}
```

As you can see from this code stump, I'm ignoring a few properties, as these properties are not needed. Other than that, I'm just mapping every Identity model into their corresponding table, as I'm using custom names (I hate the `AspNetRoles`, bla, bla, table names).

After this, I went ahead and altered my `Startup.cs` class to include the following:

```
public class Startup
{
    public StartUp(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => 
            options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseContext")));

            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
                .AddDeafultRokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            <!-- Bla, bla, bla -->
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

After making these changes, I would assume that everything was set up correctly (let me know if anything might be missing). From here I can create my init migration by running the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add init
```

I can see that a `Migrations` folder is added to my project.

**Problem 1:** Shouldn't it create a `Configuration.cs` class in my migrations folder, where I can seed the database?

I would also assume that I should be able to update the database with the following command:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

**Problem 2:** But that gives me the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

*Stack trace*:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MySQL.Data.Entity.Migrations.MySQLHistoryRepository.get_ExistsSql()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DatabaseUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

**QUESTION**

This is the first time I'm using EF Code-first with a MySQL server in ASP.NET Core, which means that I'm basically using this without sufficient knowledge.

Comment: Migration seeding has been removed in EF Core. See [EnsureSeedData](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/29/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/).